# How to bind <form:select multiple="true" ... > to List of enums in command object (Spring MVC)?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Here is my simple test class (command object class)

```
public class Test {
private List<MyEnum> list;

//setters and getters
}
```

and here is the part od JSP page:

```
<form:form ......>
<form:select multiple="true" path="list" items="enumvalues">
</form:form>
```

I would like to bind all selected items from jsp list to my command object list. What is the best way to do this? I know, that I need to write some custom editors but after some tests I have no idea how to achieve that.

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have proper access to `list` in JSP, this should work:

```
<form:form ...>
  <form:select multiple="true" path="list">
    <form:options />
  </form:select>
</form:form>
```

P.S. If you want `options` have different readable name than value, just override enum value's `toString()` and Spring MVC will magically use it as description.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `<form:options />` did the work instead of `items` option inside `<form:select>` tag.

Comment: @PiratDrogowy can you provide a solution to this for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730760/springmvc-how-to-bind-a-multi-select-option-element